# Last parameter of my URL it's splitting (i'm using zxing qr scan, php and prefix and suffix variables)

Tags: php, qr-code, zxing

I have a API of parking car, and i use it like for example: (i will show the real code) www.site.com/ticket/{NUMBER OF TICKET}/uid=31231&apikey=123123 (this last parameter, the api key don't appear on final link but the uid parameter yes)

Well.. I'm using ZXING to generate the ticket as I use... so I have a QR with only text (number of ticket). And the code:

```
<form action="#"><method="post">
<?php
$prefixoconsulta = "http://zxing.appspot.com/scan?ret=https://demonstracao.parkingplus.com.br/servicos/2/ticket/";
$sufixoconsulta = "?udid=1234&apiKey=123123";
$url=$prefixoconsulta . ' ' . $sufixoconsulta;
?>

(<a href="<?php echo $prefixoconsulta ?>{CODE}<?php echo $sufixoconsulta ?>">Ler QR Code</a>):
            <input type="text" name="cod" value=""/>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

So... i need to return a url like this:

https://demonstracao.parkingplus.com.br/servicos/2/ticket/55432411?udid=1234&apiKey=123123

But i have a url like this: :-(

```
https://demonstracao.parkingplus.com.br/servicos/2/ticket/55432411?udid=1234
```

So... the prefix and suffix variables are correct because the uid go to link, but the last parameter for some reason don't go.

Maybe the "&" it's splitting my url? I will keep trying a solution, if I have success i post the solution here, thanks in advance.

Comment: P.S.: I change the ApiKey numbe rfor obvious reasons.

Comment: Seems like it working, what version of php you use? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8343e00644fa038bc3627a8a6ca1081c58ea9604

Comment: Yes, the & are splitting my url. And now? i use a character code of something to put & without split my url?

Comment: I use PHP7 version

Comment: Remembering, before i click the link appears normal like http://zxing.appspot.com/scan?ret=https://demonstracao.parkingplus.com.br/servicos/2/ticket/{CODE}?udid=1234&apiKey=123

Comment: I tried to put %26 (& encoded) in place of & but same result.

Comment: Why you are sending a POST request with GET parameters? Couldn't you send GET request with udid and apiKey set as hidden form inputs?

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH, i did this mistake. i simply change the method for get and voi la :D